# Flutter showing error while using InkeWell (dirty State)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

My Flutter project ain't working, as I used a inkwell for a text, so that when the user clicks on the text it Navigates to another page,and it gets error saying dirty state whenever I try to run it,

```
 const SizedBox(width: 167.5),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: ((context) => const PopAnime()))),
                    child: const Text(
                      "See all >",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
```

[[image: error code]][1[image: ]]

Comment: can you include full sample widget ? including `PopAnime`

Comment: where do you place this widget?

Comment: The provided code is correct. Worked perfectly for me. Can you provide the full code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/BLACKxSPADES/9e1fdf29b35daf24d69baf3bd40e1ac1 can you please refer here

Answer (score 0):

```
InkWell(
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: ((context) => const PopAnime()),
            ),
          ),
          child: const Text(
            "See all >",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
        )
```

you can use navigator like this

Comment: Nope, the result is same